# When I use boolean modifier, appear weird shadow (I even dont know it's shadow or not though)

Tags: modifiers, shadows

## Version

2.83

## Problem

▼before
[image]

▼after using boolean modifier
[image]

[image]

It looks like shadow, but when I use light, this black line doesnt move. So it's not shadow I think.
I need to remove this weird line.

Comment: These are newly generated faces (triangulated). If you Apply the modifier and switch to edit mode you can see them. Usually it is a Face Normal issue. Topology is very bad. Also if other modifiers go after (like Bevel or Subsurf) issue arrise even more.

Comment: It sounds we cant solve it so far, is it right?

Comment: You would have to change topo of the wall (add more vertices). Attach the blend file so we can check. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I cant upload file from this website, Let me know if u know other way to share file please. maybe google drive isnt good idea here.   I mean something without necessary account like blend-exchange.

Comment: Leave in the blend only objects that matters (simplify as possible). On the link you just drag&drop blend, check two checkmarks and copy paste url of your Q into field below. ... or use Google drive I will upload blend here for you now (if it really doesnt work for you, but I dont know what could be a reason.